# How do you add a non-editable field to a custom admin form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to add an `editable=False` field to a custom admin form, but I am getting an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'help_num' cannot be specified for 
Investigation model form as it is a non-editable field
```

This is true, in my model I have it set as such:

models.py

```
help_num = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True, default=increment_helpdesk_number, editable=False)
```

forms.py

```
class HelpDeskModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = HelpDesk
      fields = [
          "help_num",
          "help_types",
           ...
          "help_summary"
          ]
```

admin.py

```
class HelpDeskModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('help_num',)
    form = HelpDeskModelForm
```

I added the `readonly` to admin.py, but am still getting the error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to remove the non-editable field from your class form list of fields :

```
class HelpDeskModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = HelpDesk
      fields = [
          #"help_num",
          "help_types",
           ...
          "help_summary"
          ]
```

And keep the read-only fields in the ModelAdmin like you did :

```
class HelpDeskModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('help_num',)
    form = HelpDeskModelForm
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that.  Maybe I did a typo when I tried.  Thanks.  Marking answer now.