# How to check an item in a tuple in a tuple with inconsistent items

Tags: python, django, tuples

I have a tuple that has some single items in it as well as some more 2 item tuples in it, and I need to be able to check the 2 item tuples for a specific match.

I have tried specifying the 2 item tuple to avoid the problem, but I am using django and it is a fieldset field item and if I specify down to the 2 item tuple that I know the item I'm looking for is in, I can't perform the operation that the check is testing for. The django error that comes up is "cannot be specified for myModel model form as it is a non-editable field". I also don't think that I can do a nested for loop because not all items in the tuple are nested tuples. I've also tried to make a testing variable as a boolean of if the item is there or not, but then I get the error thrown when I try and do the if statement, even though it should be skipped due to the fact that the item is actually present in the list.

I've looked at a lot of the answers here and on the web in general and I haven't been able to find a good answer.

```py
field = ('item1', 'item2', ('item3', 'item4'), 'item5')
if 'item3' not in field:
    field += ('item3', 'item5', 'item6')
    print('not there')
else:
    print('there')

# if it recognized that the item was there it would print 'there' 
# but it actually prints 'not there' and adds the items
```

Those lines would ideally see 'item3' and not add the other fields in and create a duplicate, but instead it is adding the extra items because  the if/in cannot/isn't going into that nested tuple.

If I try and specify the inner tuple (i.e. if 'item3' not in field[2]) in my django project I get the "cannot be specified for myModel model form as it is a non-editable field" because 'item3' is an item in the fieldset fields.

So, I guess there are two specific questions: 
1. how to check for nested tuple matches when there are inconsistent items in the tuple (single items, and nested tuples)?
2. why would knowing that there is this item in the fieldset throw that error because the operation causing it should be skipped in the first place?

Any help or advice anyone could give me would be Very appreciated and helpful!

Comment: It is `field[2]`, since indices are zero-based. You might want to consider first "flattening" the tuple.

Comment: That's a good thought, but how would I deal with that, since there aren't consistent nested tuples? from what I've seen you'd have to do a list comprehension or for loops taking the nested tuples out of a nest, but not all of my items are nested tuples?

Comment: you can use recursion and check with `isinstance(..., tuple)` if something is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

If the tuple has an indefinite "deepness" level (there can be tuple inside tuple inside tuple...) you can try a simple recursive function:

```py
def tuple_in_recursive(field, item):
    for element in field:
        if type(element) == tuple:
            if tuple_in_recursive(element, item):
                return True
        else:
            if element == item:
                return True
    return False
```

If you know that there are at most 2 level you can do it with 2 nested loops instead, but the principle is the same.
In any case this function could be generalized to work with every data structure, but it seems you only have tuples and basic elements, so it is sufficient.

In any case I see that you concatenate items to the tuple. This is not a recommended behavior cause tuples are immutable, so the + operator (the appending) could possibly create a new tuple and destroy the old one, that is highly inefficient (but it depends on the interpreter implementation). Then is a readability issue because seeing a tuple I expect that it is not modified.
So why don't you use a list?

For the Django problem I see a related question here: [How do you add a non-editable field to a custom admin form in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699915/how-do-you-add-a-non-editable-field-to-a-custom-admin-form-in-django) 
It seems that is related to a single field (what you call item) and not the structure itself

Another solution could be to flatten the tuple, so you won't have any nested tuple. But be aware that you could lose information; maybe you need to have the nested tuples, the code is a little modification to the one above, but it doesn't work inplace:

```py
def flatten(field):
    for index, element in enumerate(field):
        if type(element) == tuple:
            return field[:index] + flatten(field[index]) + flatten(field[index + 1:])
    return field
```

Comment: thank you!
that correctly assess if the item is in the list, but then I get the django error. I have tried to use a list, but being part of a django fieldset I'm pretty sure that it has to be a tuple to be correctly used.

Comment: @Rphillips Maybe this will help help you for the Django error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699915/how-do-you-add-a-non-editable-field-to-a-custom-admin-form-in-django
I'll update the answer